# Current Sensing Transformer Overload

Tags: transformer

When using a [AC Current Sensing Transformer](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/grove-electricity-sensor-p-777.html) (5A MAX) what will happen if a current larger than the maximum rating is utilized (like 15A). Will the readings simply be out of range or is there greater risks involved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing terrible will happen. When the core saturates, the voltage/current on the secondary will stop rising — in other words, the reading will no longer be accurate.

But you still need to make sure that the signal coming off the secondary won't exceed the limits of whatever it is attached to, using some sort of clamping circuit if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The current transformer has a single turn input (the wire passing through it) surrounded by a magnetic ring core. Output is taken from a multi-turn secondary (step up) winding . Like any transformer if you exceed the current rating the core will go into saturation and distort the waveform and produce inaccurate readings.